# What are the typical human entry points to a Java EE application?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, architecture

Right now I am creating a checklist for my juniors, there they can go through it to check if they have got all requirements from the customer. Especially what entrypoints to the application can come up.

In my eyes there are following entry points which human can trigger to a Java EE 7 application. (independent from the GUI framework)

- UI (e.g. Browser, Rich-Application)
- CLI (command line)
- E-Mail (may be added to a different place also)

Under entry point I understand a manual user interaction, which a end-user have to trigger. Like accessing the UI to your application, or by sending a e-mail to your application or maybe a more sofisticated "CLI" interface.

So for me an acceptable answer would be to think around and to get a list of possible ways users could interact with the application. And the interaction would be direct to the application.

Like in the examples above following human interactions may be considered (do I miss some here?):

- Mouse click
- keyboard interaction
- touch on screens

I am wondering if I have got all entry points to a Java EE 7 application.

This question was already here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25011657/what-are-the-typical-entry-points-to-a-java-ee-application , but it was voted to be to broad, so I try to narrow the questions down.

Comment: How do you define an "entry point"?

Comment: Thx for the question. Will update my question

Comment: Its still pretty vague what the boundaries of 'human entry points' are. Given your email example, I would also say web services and JMS messages apply. Disregarding that, I wonder what would be any acceptable -answer- to this question within the clearly defined rules of SO.

Comment: okay Gimby, I will try to clearify again. Human interactions cannot be JMS, since JMS is usually implemented by a script, application. Same to web services. You seldomly use a webservice without a UI (of course from enduser perspective). About your question, what a acceptable answer may be, all that may extend the above list of human interactions but not interactions, which may be redirected by one of the new or already given entry points.

Comment: It is a worthy effort to narrow your first question. BTW you could also have tried to edit your first question instead of asking a new one : it would have gone in re-open queue ... but with little chance of being re-opened. Without saying *why* you ask the question, and what is your *actual* problem you are off-topic here

Comment: IMO, your question still does not make sense. How does it relate to Java EE at all (it's more about interaction patterns)? As @SergeBallesta already suggested, you should tell us **why** you ask this question.

Comment: Hello all, many thanks for helping me to get my question to the point. I have added why I'm asking the question. @home, yes you are right it is not specific to JavaEE now, but the next questions based on this will be specific to JavaEE.